# Email form submit shows email log

Tags: forms, email, form-submit, postmark

I recently completed my 1.0 version of my website and now that I uploaded it to dreamhost’s server, I’m having issues submitting the email form. When I host it locally, everything goes through with no problems. However, when on the server, it displays the email log:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.postmarkapp.com ESMTP sc-iad-smtp2
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO [website]
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.postmarkapp.com250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 20480000250-VRFY250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: NzI2NzExNWItNzYwNC00ZDE2LTk0MmEtNDIwM2Y5NTM2Njk5
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: NzI2NzExNWItNzYwNC00ZDE2LTk0MmEtNDIwM2Y5NTM2Njk5
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
```

I’m currently using the postmark app while hosted on dreamhost.

I’ve tried editing this field:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "There was a problem sending the email:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
```

by adding:

```
else {
        header (“Location: [insert form confirmation page here]”)
}
```

But it just logs the command on the page. Can someone please help me understand why this is happening on the server and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the official php library? http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-official-libs.html#php Where are you seeing the email log, in the email that it sends or on your server?

Comment: So I fill out my form and click submit to test and it shows the first box containing code in my original post. When I host it locally, it goes through just fine when I click submit.

Comment: Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: There could be a php version difference between your local computer and Dreamhost. Do you know which version you're both running? Also, I'm not sure Dreamhost will allow external SMTP connections, it may be blocked on their side. Can you check that? If you use the php API library linked above you can eliminate the need for SMTP.